# QGIS cannot select certain polygon

Tags: qgis

I have a shapefile from an external source. I cannot select a certian polygon. As shown in the attached picture. Any ideas how to see what the problem is?

[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CahVa.jpg)

Regards

Comment: It might be a hole in a polygon.

Comment: Could you maybe provide a (wfs) link to the layer? As @swatchai pointed out the polygon might be missing or the topology could be broken, but it's impossible to tell the screenshot